# Loop out of a JavaScript array every 25 Iterations

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to call a separate function after building a string value after every 25 iterations of an array.

I have

```
    for (var index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    let names = names +" " +  array[index]["Last_Name"]

    // and every time the index hits 25 or 50 or 75 etc it calls another function
     this.anotherFunction(names);
  
     }
```

Is this possible without hardcoding the 25/50/75/100 etc values? or using some type of math function?

Comment: I am concerned that you are building a giant string by using a loop. Looking beyond your exact question, would `array.map(e => e.Last_Name).join(' ')` be a better way to do this? Or at least something like `array.slice(index, index+25).map(e => e.Last_name).join(' ')` (ensuring to increment index by 25 on each loop).

Answer (score 3):

Modulo?

```
if (index && index % 25 === 0) {
  this.anotherFunction(names);
}
```

Comment: Here's the MDN for Remainder/Modulo for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder

Comment: I think the condition `(index+1) % 25 === 0` would be better, since the proposed answer will first activate on the 26th iteration (i.e. when index is 25).